# How to draw under-text grid lines in minipage?

Tags: grids, grid-typesetting, underline

I want to achieve like shown below:

[image]

But the only thing I can get with `ulem` is:

[image]

With the code below:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}

    \uline{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam non
    vulputate neque, sit amet dictum dolor. Vestibulum auctor ante nec arcu 
    faucibus lacinia.}

    \begin{center}
      \uline{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam non
      vulputate neque, sit amet dictum dolor. Vestibulum auctor ante nec arcu 
      faucibus lacinia.}
    \end{center}

  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! The fist one can be obtained by adding `\hfill`: `\uline{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam non
    vulputate neque, sit amet dictum dolor. Vestibulum auctor ante nec arcu 
    faucibus lacinia.\hfill{}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution uses `\vbox` to format the text and `\vsplit` to underline each line.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand{\lined}[1]% #1 = paragraph text
{\bgroup
  \setbox0=\vbox{\strut #1\strut}%
  \dimen0=0pt
  \loop\ifdim\ht0>0pt
    \dimen1=\dimexpr\ht0 - \baselineskip\relax
    \setbox1=\vsplit0 to \ht\strutbox
    \advance\dimen1 by -\ht0
    \noindent\raisebox{-\dimen0}[\ht\strutbox][\dp\strutbox]{\box1}%
    %\llap{\the\dimen0~\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}% show baseline
    \advance\dimen0 by \dimen1
    \vspace{-0.2ex}\hrule\vskip 0.2ex % aesthetic tweak
  \repeat
\egroup}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
    \parindent=\bibindent
    %\huge
    \lined{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam non
    vulputate neque, sit amet dictum dolor. Vestibulum auctor ante nec arcu 
    faucibus lacinia.}

    \begin{center}
      \lined{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam non
      vulputate neque, sit amet dictum dolor. Vestibulum auctor ante nec arcu 
      faucibus lacinia.}
    \end{center}

  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works fine in default font size. But when l changed to `\Huge` size, there comes some alignment problems. How to fix it? [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/AovXfhy.png)

Comment: Yeah.  It turns out that \vsplit is not acting consistently.  It grabs 34.67912pt the first line, 29.043pt the second line, then settles down to 30pt per line.  The net result is that the baseline of \box1 is not where it should be.  Alas, most of my attempts to fix this result in infinite loops.